# Newbie needing help Installing full OS on USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

New to Linux and Ubuntu here.... Looking to try Ubuntu but don't want to mess up main drive and install it on there yet till I know I like it. I have OS installed on USB so I can boot into it but then I an locked into the try version or install full thing. Can I install the whole OS on the USB for now until I decide I like it??

Thanks in Advance everyone!

Comment: You haven't provided any release details, but yes I've tested Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (default `ubiquity` installer, didn't try *di* installer) and was able to install it to thumb-drive, however was unable to do the same with Lubuntu 20.04 LTS using the default `calamares` installer. Both can be written to a thumb-drive with the use of *persistence* though, and this will apply to all Ubuntu release & *flavors* I believe.  ie. yes but there can be technicalities depending on release, *flavor*, ISO you start with etc.

Comment: Yeah. I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a thumb drive so I can boot from USB to at least try it out. But now I am trying to figure out whether I want to dual boot, run just Ubuntu on my Laptop or have Ubuntu on another Thumb Drive. I am totally new to Linux and everything that comes with it but up to trying it and see what I think

Comment: I now know your release (20.04), but not if you're talking about a desktop ISO, server ISO, or other.. In my first comment I mentioned Lubuntu 18.04 (Lubuntu is desktop only) with default ISO/installer (which uses `ubiquity`) rather than the alternate ISO (the *di* I didn't test), let alone 18.04 offers 18.04.1, 18.04.2 etc (20.04 has a 20.04.1 so far)   Regardless, writing it with *persistence* is probably easiest, even if not as fast as an installed version (assuming you're talking desktop).

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Desktop ISO. Just thinking about running it on my laptop and thats it until I like it then I might put it on my Desktop as well. But will not be for Server stuff. Dont mess with any of that. Haha.

Sorry, I am just new with all this and trying to learn all the terms and stuff. Haha. Currently making a recovery Drive of my Windows on a USB in case I mess anything up

Comment: There are several methods of varying difficulty on this page for making a Full install to USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: C.S, Can you tell me.... When I am trying to partition the USB. I cant do the last step with making the rest of free space as a EXT partition cause it says I have 4 primary already. Do you know which ones need to be primary and which ones can be Extended Partitions?

Comment: If you are trying the first method on the pae I mentioned, did you "Select Device tab and create a GPT partition table on the Target drive" in GParted? This method only used primary partitions, with GPT you can have very many partitions. The method below is better suited for a first attempt at Full install USB. This is also the answer by sudodus on the other page.

Comment: I actually got it figured out. Picked the wrong partition table. Whoops! Almost finished but trying to figure out where to get files and move them

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Method for Making Full Install of Ubuntu to USB.

The creator of **mkusb** has been perfecting the use of image files for creating Full installs of Ubuntu on USB. Download Image file is 1.5GB, not 15GB.

- Download https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz
- Decompress file using 7Zip.
- Flash to USB using Rufus, Etcher, Image Writer, etc.
- Password is "changeme", Change it.

MD5Sum can be found here: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/md5sum.txt.asc